# "This extension is disabled by the environment"

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, prettier, elementary-os

I had been using VS Code on Elementary OS (essentially Ubuntu 18.04) with Prettier successfully. Some time recently Prettier stopped working (not sure when or how, but guessing it was with a VS Code update). I tried following all the posts I found - nothing has worked so far.

What I did last was remove VSCode using:

```
sudo apt remove code
```

and I also manually deleted the `.vscode`  directory. Then I reinstalled VS Code using:

```
sudo apt install code
```

so now VSCode is at version 1.82.2.

Then I installed Prettier (latest version, v10.1.0). So all I have now is VS Code and one extension. But the extension always appears Disabled. And apparently the extension is "disabled by the environment".

[image: Prettier - This extension is disabled by the environment.]

So even though Prettier is installed it does not appear as an option in the "Default Formatter" drop-down:

[image: Prettier Missing among Default Formatter Choices]

Many of the posts I have read suggest setting the Default Formatter as the fix for Prettier problems, but I don't even have it as an option.

I guess it makes sense that "esbenp.prettier-vscode" is unrecognized in my settings.json.

[image: settings.json]

Anyone know how to get Prettier working again?

Comment: are you invoking VS Code from the command line? If so, what arguments are you passing it? did you pass `--disable-extensions` or `disable-extension <...>` ? related source code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1b32ba2308db7680b0acdfbcec6e89560a4d8c45/src/vs/workbench/services/extensionManagement/browser/extensionEnablementService.ts#L370

Comment: Yes, I am invoking VS Code from the command line, but using just “code ./“.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had something called "Extension Bisect" running in the background. I'm guessing this is a native service within VSCode rather than an extension. I have several popups open when I launch VSCode suggesting extensions I should install and I have gotten into the bad habit of simply closing all of them. I didn't notice that one of these was informing me about "Bisect" disabling several extensions. The popup gave me the option of uninstalling or disabling Bisect (I don't recall which and I haven't found other posts to clarify). After doing so (i.e. uninstalling or disabling) Prettier started working as expected.